# org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to run the following command to create a user with MongoDB Java Driver,

```
    client = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("db_1");

    Document createUserCommand = new Document();
    createUserCommand.put("createUser", "abc");
    createUserCommand.put("pwd", "abc");
    createUserCommand.put("roles", new String[]{"userAdmin", "read", "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "dbOwner"});         database.runCommand(createUserCommand);
```

But following exception occurred:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class [Ljava.lang.String;.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:174)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:189)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:131)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
```

Looks the roles field which is an array leads to this problem, can some take a look at this problem? Thanks

Comment: Looks like I figured out the problem,

    createUserCommand.put("roles", new String[]{"userAdmin", "read", "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "dbOwner"});         database.runCommand(createUserCommand);

should be 
List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
roles.add("userAdmin);
...

    createUserCommand.put("roles", roles);         database.runCommand(createUserCommand);

Looks like it support List, not Array, which is really ugly.

Comment: Post it as an answer. It helped me too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
createUserCommand.put("roles", new String[]{"userAdmin", "read", "readWrite", "dbAdmin", "dbOwner"});
 database.runCommand(createUserCommand);
```

should be

```
List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>(); 
roles.add("userAdmin); ... createUserCommand.put("roles", roles); database.runCommand(createUserCommand);
```

Looks like it support List, not Array, which is really ugl

Comment: query data also has this problem after String[] --> List<String> solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may run into this issue with Kotlin:

```
val roles: List<String> = arrayListOf("role1", "role2")
```